# UITextView doesn't show InputAccessoryView on first click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I use the `UITextViewDelegate` and add a `InputAccessoryView` in `textViewDidBeginEditing:`

```
[textView setInputAccessoryView:doneBar];
```

The doneBar is not nil and it appears on second opening.

Has anyone else this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I imagine when the code has reached `textViewDidBeginEditing:` that it is too late to make changes to the UI.  Perhaps you can move your code to an earlier event, maybe `textViewShouldBeginEditing:`

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for days. You're the man!

Comment: After two years I still can't get over how great StackOverflow is. I would have been tearing my hair out for ages but now I think I'm spoilt! Thanks very much for this.

Comment: Remember: textView.delegate = self;

Comment: After 6 years you posted your answer: great thanks !